# How to generate numpy array with skewed distribution given maximum,minimum and number of points to be generated

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution, skew

I am trying to generate latitudes from latitude boundary(min,max latitudes and number of points) .

I have two choices to generate this :

Using multiple probability distribution and generating x with 1 probability distribution ,as that wont be normal

Or

make a distribution with skew introduced.
The main aim is getting a non normal distributed array points .

I might be doing a conceptual mistake here.

```
def array_gen(min,max):
    new_lat_ = np.linspace(min,max,1000)
    a = 3
    r = skewnorm.rvs(a, size=1000)
    #not sure how to use the new_lat_
    arr = skewnorm.pdf(new_lat_, *skewnorm.fit(new_lat_))
    ax.hist(r, density=True,histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
    ax.hist(arr, density=True,histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
    return arr 
array = array_gen(12.786963,13.140868)
fig
```

I expect a distribution that is skewed I get it but it isn't in the range I expected .Expected range = (12.786963,13.140868)

0.43939953, 0.75707352, 0.63534797, 0.40377254, 0.27907808,
   0.23454434, 0.11875663, 0.07422289, 0.02375133, 0.00296892
   -0.1491852 ,  0.1876381 ,  0.5244614 ,  0.8612847 ,  1.198108,
   1.53493129,  1.87175459,  2.20857789,  2.54540119,  2.88222449,
   3.21904779

Comment: What parameters did you feed it? What range did you expect?

Comment: (12.786963,13.140868). Edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see you using the parameters `min` and `max` other than in `new_lat_`, and I don't see you using `new_lat_` anywhere. Why would you expect the values of `min` and `max` to affect `r`?

Comment: Now the question is complete. Sorry for the errors.